# mongo db (mongodb.service) failed, status 14

Tags: database, mongodb, web

I am experiencing the following problem using mongodb.

This is the error, when I check the status:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIIy.png) (mongodb.service, status 14)

[Screenshot of code in the mongod.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwHMC.png)

[Screenshot of the log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diuf5.png)

I have tried uninstalling mongodb following every step from the website and install everything again and when I check the status I still get the same error. I have posted the screenshot of the error. 
I am using MacBook pro if this matters.

Would really appreciate, if someone can help me fix this.

Comment: see if there's anything in log file. You can find log file path in `/etc/mongod.conf`.

Comment: @yaoxing Yes there is, I have added another screenshot of the code inside the file as it is too long to paste it here..

Comment: You need to take a loot at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. See if there's anything interesting inside.

Comment: I have attached screenshot of the log file.

Answer (score 41):

By changing the owner to monogdb user of
/var/lib/mongodb and /tmp/mongodb-27017.lock has worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Comment: For mongo4 use: sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/

Comment: This file ownership fix is necessary because if you follow [the MongoDB tutorial][1], you might start the mongod from the command line, which changes the ownership of 2 files in your data directory (first fix that @Roshan mentions).  After the file ownership changes, mongod can no longer be started as a service (using the config file) until you revert the file ownership, as described in this solution.

  [1] https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: I ran above mentioned commands then `sudo systemctl enable --now mongod` and `sudo systemctl status mongod` this worked for me!

Answer (score 35):

It seems from the log you have a unclean shutdown before. Or, it could also indicates that `mongod` is already running.
First, make sure `mongod` is not running already

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

If it's not, remove the file:

```
rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Then try `systemctl start mongod` to start MongoDB again.

Comment: This was the solve to get the mongod service running on CentOS 8 with MongoDB v4.4.2

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 18.04 and MongoDB v4.4.5

Comment: It worked for CentOS 7 with MongoDB 4.4.6. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

After rebooting in the command line,it fixed to problem,don’t know why after stopping mongo and uninstalling and installing it didn’t fix the problem, but after reboot everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04**

```
Go to the TMP directory: cd /tmp
Check if you have the mongodb sock file: ls *.sock
Change the user:group permission: chown mongodb:mongodb <YOUR_SOCK>
Start MongoDB: sudo service mongod start
Check the MongoDB status: sudo service mongod status
```

If this does not work you can try

```
sudo reboot
```

Please see here : https://medium.com/@gabrielpires/mongodb-ubuntu-16-04-code-exited-status-14-aws-lightsail-problem-417ffc78cb11

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and even though the permissions were all okay, the service failed to start. I had a look at the mongodb log

```
sudo tail -40 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

It said that the database was shutdown unexpectedly and needed to be repaired. I ran

```
sudo mongod --repair --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

This fixed the database, but now changed the permissions. You will need to do the chown steps again.

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Start the mongod service. It would be up & running now.

Answer (score 1):

Same happended with `CentOS Stream 8`

the user for mongodb service is `mongo` and group is also `mongo`

`sudo chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

Resolved, after checking the logfile, showing `mongodb-27017.sock` failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Was a SELinux blocking the normal execution.
So, I did:

```
# ausearch -c 'mongod' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mongod
# semodule -X 300 -i my-mongod.pp
```

and then:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongod
```

and check:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```