# mongoDB: child process failed, exited with 1 & 14

Tags: mongodb

I have already tried it with the following thread but it didn't help me:
[ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1,mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293242/error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-1-mongodb)
Tried that:
`sudo mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Result:

```
forked process: 2887
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 48
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

Tried the following as well:
`sudo systemctl start mongod`

One of the lines in the error message say:
`ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14`

Would appreciate any help. mongod was working pretty well until I have started trying to implement a replica set.

Comment: What do you have in the log `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`? What do you get when you start without `--fork`? (like advised in the error)

Comment: Check out [mongo db (mongodb.service) failed, status 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469608/mongo-db-mongodb-service-failed-status-14)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command on the terminal:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

It should start the MongoDB server and allocate a port for it. You can exit out of the server and then try the command again and it should work.